# Android json loses utf-8 encoding

Tags: android, json, encoding, utf-8

HI I have a strange problem. I have checked around everywhere but the answers that I have found do not apply to my problem. I have a server request which returns me this string as an answer and the encoding is fine. For example I get:

```
{"codi":-10,"obj":"S'ha denegat la connexi\u00c3\u00b3! El vostre compte o b\u00c3\u00a9 ha sigut bloquejat o b\u00c3\u00a9 encara no l'heu activat."}
```

which is fine. But once I transform this string into json it looses the utf-8:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
```

json has this value:

```
{"obj":"S'ha denegat la connexiÃ³! El vostre compte o bÃ© ha sigut bloquejat o bÃ© encara no l'heu activat.","codi":-10}
```

I just don't know what to do to change that. I have tried using:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
```

Is there a better json library? thnks

EDIT this is how I get the answer from server:

```
public void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();


        if (entity != null) {


    response = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
             Log.d("TEST", response);
             //Toast.makeText(this, jsonText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT2: as requested I include the results of:

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity)));

[123, 34, 99, 111, 100, 105, 34, 58, 45, 49, 48, 44, 34, 111, 98, 106, 34, 58, 34, 83, 39, 104, 97, 32, 100, 101, 110, 101, 103, 97, 116, 32, 108, 97, 32, 99, 111, 110, 110, 101, 120, 105, 92, 117, 48, 48, 99, 51, 92, 117, 48, 48, 98, 51, 33, 32, 69, 108, 32, 118, 111, 115, 116, 114, 101, 32, 99, 111, 109, 112, 116, 101, 32, 111, 32, 98, 92, 117, 48, 48, 99, 51, 92, 117, 48, 48, 97, 57, 32, 104, 97, 32, 115, 105, 103, 117, 116, 32, 98, 108, 111, 113, 117, 101, 106, 97, 116, 32, 111, 32, 98, 92, 117, 48, 48, 99, 51, 92, 117, 48, 48, 97, 57, 32, 101, 110, 99, 97, 114, 97, 32, 110, 111, 32, 108, 39, 104, 101, 117, 32, 97, 99, 116, 105, 118, 97, 116, 46, 34, 125]

Comment: How are you getting the second form of the JSON? My guess is that the problem is how you're converting the object back to text.

Comment: NO I am not converting anything back. I get the String form server which is fine but once it is converted to json the encoding is all wrong. I use Rest Client to get the results from server. These results are fine but I guess the method new JSONObject(response) just doesn't use utf-8

Comment: If you start out with a String that contains (for instance) the letters Ã (0xc3) and ³ (0xb3) you're going to get the exact same characters out of the JSON object. How are you receiving the data? As a String / stream of bytes? How are you converting it into the "response" String?

Comment: @vallllll: Of course you're converting - you've parsed it to a `JSONObject` and then you've presented us with a string to include in the post. How did you get that string? If you ask the JSON value of its `obj` value, and then inspect the characters one at a time in the debugger, what do you see?

Comment: I have updated the question accroding to your questions. When I debug if I look at the value of json in the variables value (like when you pass over with the mouse on your variable or on the right box and it's value is not UTF-8. I can see strange caracters. Then I use this json object (what I have written is a string but in reality is the JSONobject). I do the folowing: String reason=json.getString("obj"); and then I use it as message for a dialog and I get the strange caracters.

Comment: I have checked everywhere and the conclusion i got is: the enconding gets messed up when I encode the String "response" into a json object

Comment: The JSONObject class doesn't do anything to the character set - it operates on the character level. If you feel inclined, dump the output of Arrays.toString(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity)) and include in your question, this will let us see exactly, byte for byte, what you are getting from the server.

Comment: thanks Jens I have included the result in my answer above. From what I know non ascii code should be >128 but non of these codes are. Does it mean they're all ascii?

Comment: Yep, that server is returning the result as ASCII with all non-ascii characters encoded as unicode escape sequences.

Comment: does it mean it is the server code that needs to be modified?

Comment: Yes, it should probably be fixed as this wouldn't be a problem if the server didn't insist on encoding the bytes that makes up a Unicode code point separately.